# Why can't overloaded operator accept those parameters using reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I was doing programming exercise and I'm left in doubt why parameters of this overloaded operator need to be pointers and not references.

```
vector<Subject> studentSuccess= student(new Date(18, 06, 2019, 10, 15), new Date(21, 06, 2019, 10, 10));
```

overloaded operator in class needs to be like this to work:

```
vector<Subject> operator()(Date* start, Date* end) {..}
```

Question is why it can't work this way:

```
vector<Subject> operator()(Date& start, Date& end) {..}
```

Comment: Who says it can't work that way?

Comment: Because C++ is not Java. Drop superfluous dynamic allocation.

Comment: It works this way because that is simply the way the function author coded it. Both approaches work in general, it is just a matter of picking the desired one, and the author chose to use pointers. Though, in the first case, this would be safer: `Date d1(18, 06, 2019, 10, 15); Date d2(21, 06, 2019, 10, 10); vector<Subject> studentSuccess = student(&d1, &d2);` unless `student::operator()` is expected to take ownership of the `Date*` pointers.

Comment: I tried to use references and it won't work

Comment: If `operator()` is declared to take `Date*` pointers, you can't pass it `Date&` references instead. You have to match what the declaration says to use.

Comment: More detail on the operator and how it function and we may be able to give you a nice, satisfying concrete answer. Without it you're not getting much better than what Yuri and Remy have pitched.

Comment: Because operator `new` returns a pointer, not a reference.    If you pass a pointer to a function, it is necessary for that function to accept a pointer somehow.   Get rid of the keyword `new` in your example, supply a version of your function that accept `const` reference, and your code will work.